# calculate the s-number for a natural number using Prolog

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I am a total novice to Prolog and still am getting used to its logic.

I have a task to create functions that turn a natural number into an "S-number" and vice versa.

So Number 0 would be `0`.
Number 1 would be `s(0)`.
Number 2 would be `s(s(0))`.
And so on.

```
nat(0).
nat(s(0)):- nat(X).
```

The function for finding a natural number for a given S-number I already have:

```
s2nat(0, 0) :- !.
s2nat(s(S),Number) :- s2nat(S,NewNumber), Number is NewNumber + 1.
```

So `?- s2nat(s(s(s(0))), X)` would give `X=3` as an output.

Now I need to write a function that does the opposite: returns an S-number for a given natural number.

And here I am stuck. I don't quite understand how to write a condition so that Prolog understands that I need `s(S)` to be returned. The condition `Number is NewNumber + 1` doesn't work anymore to go back and get to a "0".

Do you have any advice?

Comment: You make a comment like `sick logic` and then you expect help?

Comment: if `Number is NewNumber + 1` works for going up from 0, `NewNumber is Number - 1` will work for going down towards 0.

Answer (score 1):

In the recursive step, you can check if `Number > 0`, and peform recursion with `Number-1`:

```
snat(0, 0).
snat(s(S), Number) :-
    Number > 0,
    Number1 is Number-1,
    s2nat(S, Number1).
```

We can make the predicate multidirection, for example by using the `clpfd` library:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

snat(0, 0).
snat(s(X), N) :-
    N #> 0,
    N1 #= N-1,
    snat(X, N1).
```

This predicate can thus calculate the Peano representation of a number, calculate the number the Peano representation represents, validate if the given Peano number is indeed the given number, and enumerate over all possible Peano representations and their corresponding number:

```
?- snat(X, 4).
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
false.

?- snat(s(s(0)), N).
N = 2.

?- snat(s(s(0)), 2).
true.

?- snat(s(s(0)), 4).
false.

?- snat(X, N).
X = N, N = 0 ;
X = s(0),
N = 1 ;
X = s(s(0)),
N = 2 ;
X = s(s(s(0))),
N = 3 ;
X = s(s(s(s(0)))),
N = 4
```

Comment: thank you very much! My mistake was with ```Number1 is Number-1``` . I was stupidly trying to put it in the  end as the first time. Thanks a lot, in the beginning it definitely helps to get a punch from the side.